# How customize permissions in django (not in DRF)?

Tags: django, permissions

How customize permissions for updating and deleting objects just for creator (author) in view.py (CRUD classes)? I know classes LoginRequiredMixin and PermissionRequiredMixin, but I cant customize them to make permission just for creator (author) to change exact object.
I know how customize permission in DRF using class IsAdminOrReadOnly, for example:
permissions.py in DRF

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return bool(obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_staff)
```

view.py in Django (without DRF)

```
class NewsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, BaseMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = NewsForm
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/news_update.html'
```

model.py in Django (without DRF)

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The question is: How customize permissions in django (not in DRF)?
Thank you in advance. I hope you could give me piece of advice, link to the article, or documentation, or example of code to solve this problem. I've read [Custom users and permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions), but I haven't got how to solve my exact task.

Comment: can you share your code also, views and models ?

Comment: I've added code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) in your view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class NewsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, BaseMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = NewsForm
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/news_update.html'

    def test_func(self):
        news = self.get_object()
        return news.user == self.request.user
```